# PNG overlaying YT video - alignment issues across devices

Tags: html, css, youtube, png, transparency

Ive been fiddling with a lot of informationm ive found here to overlay a transparent TV PNG over a youtube video, and have succesfully gotten it to work on desktop. However I cannot get it to align correctly when viewed on mobile devices (which will be primary viewership). Is there a way I can force different CSS values depending on the device used?

```css
#panel {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 625px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#panel-tv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('images/tvoverlay.png') no-repeat center;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

#panel-content-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 24%;
  width: 720px;
  height: 405px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #000;
}

#embed-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <div id="panel-tv"></div>
  <div id="panel-content-overlay">
    <div id="panel-content">
      <div id="embed-container">
        <div style="width: 683px; " class="wp-video">

          <iframe width="710" height="399" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZI2dbyNn8PI?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It is live currently at [http://nickosteel.com](https://nickosteel.com) for your reference.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

One problem I could see is that you have the tv image larger than it needs to be, meaning it becomes a bit harder. I would do the following changes.

Container (id="panel")

- make this max-width to after your tv image and center it with
  `margin: 0 auto;`

TV image

- cut it so it had as much to the left as the right, so the panel width to the right, should be as much "transparent" to the left. That makes it much easier to align
- use it as an image (`<img />`) instead of a background, that way it will become responsive and have it's natural height (and width).
- set width `width: 100%;` (this is for the responsive part)

Video

- make it responsive, look at [this post](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-video/) for that (note you don't need any of the javascript, just html/css)
- center it

with this you are good to go for a responsive solution. It would be a bit easier to give you the changes in css and html, but for that you need to have the tv image at the right size to begin with. Hope this makes sense!

Just an opinion of mine, use classes for styling and id for javascript targets.